# Email address not displaying where I expect it to

Tags: php

I'm having a strange output problem. This is my code:

```
add_shortcode('publish_party', 'party_contact_suppliers');

function party_contact_suppliers(){
    $alerts = new WP_Query (array (
        'post_type'    => 'alert',
        'post_status' => 'publish'));
    $address_cache = get_option( 'toolset_maps_address_coordinates' );

    // Ballito
    $home_lat = -29.4872902;
    $home_lon = 31.1613188;
    echo '<h3>Ballito</h3>';
    echo '<ol>';
    while($alerts->have_posts()) {
        $alerts->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $author = get_the_author();
        $author_id = get_the_author_id();
        $emailaddress = the_author_meta('user_email',$author_id);
        $center_location = get_post_meta($id,'wpcf-center-location',true);
        $radius = get_post_meta($id,'wpcf-radius',true);
        $lat = 0;
        $lon = 0;
        foreach ($address_cache as $key => $value) {
            if ( $value['address_passed'] == $center_location ) {
                $lat = $value['lat'];
                $lon = $value['lon'];
                break;
            }
        }
        $distance = distance($lat,$lon,$home_lat,$home_lon);
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<p>Alert Post ID: '.$id.' Author Name:'.$author.' Author ID: '.$author_id.' Email Address: '.$emailaddress.'</p>';
        echo '<p>Author location: '.$center_location.' Lat: '.$lat.' Long: '.$lon.' Distance: '.$distance.'Kms</p>';
        if ($distance <= $radius) {
            echo '<p style="color:green">Distance is within radius of '.$radius.' Kms. Send email to '.$emailaddress.'</p>';
        }
        else { echo '<p style="color:red">Distance is not within radius of '.$radius.' Kms.</p>';}
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

And this is the output:

#### Ballito

  email@email.com
1. Alert Post ID: 611 Author Name:Test Author ID: 3 Email Address:

   Author location: Dipdale Rd, Malvern, Queensburgh, South Africa Lat: -29.882405 Long: 30.911583 Distance: 50.122577927515Kms

   Distance is within radius of 100 Kms. Send email to

otheremail@email.com

Alert Post ID: 609 Author Name:magicbygav Author ID: 4 Email Address:

Author location: Ridge Close, Sweetwaters, Hilton, South Africa Lat: -29.600001 Long: 30.2936253 Distance: 84.868679439733Kms

Distance is not within radius of 25 Kms.

stillanother@email.com

Alert Post ID: 599 Author Name:Gavin Author ID: 1 Email Address:

Author location: Valley View Rd, Amanzimtoti, South Africa Lat: -30.0617324 Long: 30.8777186 Distance: 69.492657639933Kms

Distance is not within radius of 50 Kms.

I don't understand why the email address is appearing above the list item and not in the two places I expect to find it. Can anyone see what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
$emailaddress = the_author_meta('user_email',$author_id);
```

`the_author_meta()` will output the value as soon as it's run, which is above everything else. If you want to put the value into a variable to echo later you should use [`get_the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/):

```
$emailaddress = get_the_author_meta('user_email',$author_id);
```

The convention in WordPress is for functions beginning with `get_` to `return` the value, while functions beginning with `the_` to `echo` the value.